# How to check callable member function existence of derived class?

Tags: c++, boost, introspection, type-traits, member-functions

I'm using [Boost.TTI](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/tti/doc/html/the_type_traits_introspection_library/tti_detail_has_member_function.html) to check member function existence. I want to check not only existing functions but also non existing functions.

Boost.TTI doesn't seem to work for derived classes even if I use `using` the target member functions.

```
#include <boost/tti/has_member_function.hpp>

BOOST_TTI_HAS_MEMBER_FUNCTION(func1);
BOOST_TTI_HAS_MEMBER_FUNCTION(func2);

struct base {
    void func1() {}
};

struct derived : base {
};

struct derived_using : base {
    using base::func1;
};

int main() {
    static_assert( has_member_function_func1<base, void>::value);
    static_assert(!has_member_function_func2<base, void>::value);

    static_assert( has_member_function_func1<derived, void>::value); // error
    static_assert(!has_member_function_func2<derived, void>::value);

    static_assert( has_member_function_func1<derived_using, void>::value); // error
    static_assert(!has_member_function_func2<derived_using, void>::value);
}
```

Runnin Demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/5XkyCoeo0xEGVm3M

I want to check the member function, not any elements (types, variables) that has the name such as `func1` `func2`.

Also I tried `std::is_invocable`. It works as I expected for derived class but compile error happens for non existing functions.

```
#include <type_traits>

struct base {
    void func1() {}
};

struct derived : base {
};

int main() {
    static_assert( std::is_invocable<decltype(&base::func1), base>::value);
    static_assert(!std::is_invocable<decltype(&base::func2), base>::value);

    static_assert( std::is_invocable<decltype(&derived::func1), derived>::value);
    static_assert(!std::is_invocable<decltype(&derived::func2), derived>::value);
}
```

Running Demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/3v9H0CFVxPnfGj3t

Is there any good way to check a member function existence that supports both derived classes and non existence member functions.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a perfect answer but I achieve my goal introducing one convention.
Adding base class alias as member type that has a specific name. In my example, the name is `base`.

Boost.TTI only check the target class, so if the target class doesn't have `base` then simply returns member function checked result. Otherwise, if the target class has the member function, then return true, if it doesn't applay the same process for `base` type.

Here is complete example:

```
#include <utility>

#include <boost/tti/has_member_function.hpp>
#include <boost/tti/has_type.hpp>

BOOST_TTI_HAS_TYPE(base);

BOOST_TTI_HAS_MEMBER_FUNCTION(func1);
BOOST_TTI_HAS_MEMBER_FUNCTION(func2);

struct b1 {
    void func1() {}
};

struct b2 {
};

struct d1 : b1 {
    using base = b1; // This convention is required
};

struct d2 : b2 {
    using base = b2;
    void func1() {}
};

template <template <typename...> typename Func, typename T, typename... Params>
constexpr bool recursive_apply() {
    if constexpr(has_type_base<T>::value) {
        return
            Func<T, Params...>::value ||
            recursive_apply<Func, typename T::base, Params...>();
    }
    else {
        return Func<T, Params...>::value;
    }
}

int main() {
    static_assert( recursive_apply<has_member_function_func1, b1, void>());
    static_assert( recursive_apply<has_member_function_func1, d1, void>());

    static_assert(!recursive_apply<has_member_function_func2, b1, void>());
    static_assert(!recursive_apply<has_member_function_func2, d1, void>());

    static_assert(!recursive_apply<has_member_function_func1, b2, void>());
    static_assert( recursive_apply<has_member_function_func1, d2, void>());
}
```

Running Demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/IFFzenEFWX4GY8OD

I use C++17 feature `if constexpr`. I tried to replace it with template partial specilization with SFINAE. But I couldn't do that, so far. The problem is template template parameter can't deduced in partial specialization.

This answer works well with C++17 and one convention `base`.